# Optimization problem on trace of rotated positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-forms, matrix-analysis

Given two $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrices $A$ and $B$, I am interested in solving the following optimization problem over $n \times n$ unitary matrices $R$:
$$
\mathrm{arg}\max_R \,\mathrm{trace}(RAR^TB)~~~\text{s.t.}~~~RR^T = I_n~.
$$
More generally, given two sets of $m$ positive definite matrices $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^m$ and $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^m$ I would like to solve:
$$
\mathrm{arg}\max_R \,\sum_i\mathrm{trace}(RA_iR^TB_i)~~~\text{s.t.}~~~RR^T = I_n~.
$$

If I recall correctly, I have seen the following inequality
$$
\mathrm{trace}(R\,\mathrm{diag}({\bf c})\,R^T\,\mathrm{diag}({\bf d})) \le {\bf c}^T{\bf d}
$$
for positive vectors ${\bf c}$ and ${\bf d}$. If this inequality is correct, then $R=I_n$ provides the optimal solution for diagonal matrices and using spectral decomposition of non-diagonal $A$ and $B$ we can solve the problem in the case of $m = 1$. Can somebody please show me how to prove this inequality? More importantly, Is there a way to solve the problem in the more general case of $m > 1$?

Comment: For two posdef matrices, it is known that $\text{trace}(AB) \ge \langle \lambda^\downarrow(A), \lambda^\uparrow(B) \rangle$, which yields the inequality that you mention (because $RAR^T$ is also positive definite), though you must be careful that $c$ and $d$ are sorted in opposite order as the $\downarrow$ and $\uparrow$ above indicate...

Comment: Your comment made me realize that I had a typo in the direction of my inequality which is related to $\mathrm{trace}(AB) \le \langle \lambda^\downarrow(A), \lambda^\downarrow(B) \rangle$. Also, my problem is $\mathrm{argmax}$ not $\mathrm{argmin}$ which is corrected now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your $B_i$ commute among themselves, and the $A_i$ commute among themselves, 
then the $m=1$ solution extends somewhat. Indeed, in that case write $A_i=V C_i V^T$,
$B_i=UD_iU^T$ where $U,V$ are unitary and $C_i,D_i$ diagonal. Now, optimizing over 
$R$ becomes the same (after the right and left multiplication by $V^T$ and $U$) 
as optimizing over $W$ orthogonal in the expression 
$$tr \sum_i WD_iW^TC_i=\sum_{j}  \sum_{i,k} w_{jk}^2D_i(k)C_i(j)=
\sum_{j,k} s_{jk} \sum_i D_i(k)C_i(j)=: \sum_{j,k} s_{jk} T(k,j),$$
where $T(k,j)=\sum_i D_i(k)C_i(j)\geq 0 $.
Here, the $s_{jk}$ form a doubly stochastic matrix. By Birkhoff's theorem, the extreme points
of the set of doubly stochastic matrices are permutations, so the optimal solution for
the above convex problem is a permutation matrix $\{s_{j,k}\}$ ; unlike the case where $\sum_i$ is trivial,
I am not sure there is a simple description of the optimizing permutation.

Remark: when $m=1$, the argument above shows the inequality you wanted:  the optimal permutation in that case is the one that orders the eigenvalues of $B$ in the same order as those of $A$.

Comment: It should be possible to solve for the optimal permutation by using the Hungarian algorithm.

Comment: This case with commuting matrices indeed reduces to solving the "linear assignment problem" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem   --- also, if the $A_i$ don't commute, but $B_i=B$, it is just $m=1$; maybe something non trivial can be said about the general case too....

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment (and given the update by the OP), it is clear that $R=UP^T$ (where $A=PDP^T$ and $B=ULU^T$) maximizes the trace. This follows because
$\text{tr}(RAR^TB) \le \langle\lambda^\downarrow(A),\lambda^\downarrow(B)\rangle$, **[Problem III.6.14, R1]** and equality can be achieved by setting $R=UP^T$.

The case with $m > 1$ is a different story. A partial observation is that if $B_i=B$ for all $i$, then the problem reduces to the $m=1$ case. Otherwise, it seems to not admit a closed form solution. If I get more time, I'll try to update this answer with further thoughts.

**[R1]** R. Bhatia, *Matrix Analysis*. Springer, 1997.

Comment: Could you provide me with a pointer to this bound? What is it called or where can I find the proof?

Comment: @Norouzi: I added a citation to this result, you can find that result, and much more related useful material in the chapter of the cited book. Best,

Answer (score 1):

You could apply Newton's method on the manifold of orthonormal matrices, using the remannian structure to define derivatives and geodesic steps. This is developed in the following paper,

> Edelman, Alan, Tomás A. Arias, and Steven T. Smith. "The geometry of algorithms with orthogonality constraints." SIAM journal on Matrix Analysis and Applications 20.2 (1998): 303-353. http://web.mit.edu/~wingated/www/introductions/stiefel-mfld.pdf